# How to use wildcard subdomain in a folder on server public_html/subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

I have a wildcard subdomain in a folder public_html/subdomain on my server. I am using php script as follows 
Just to show you what I am doing on the page:

```
 <?php
 $subdomain = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
 $subdomain = strtolower(array_shift($subdomain));
 echo ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $subdomain));
?>
```

The problem is when  example.domain.co.uk is typed in it returns the top level public_html/index.php file and not the public_html/subdomain/index.php

I had this working before but I may have changed the .htaccess by error

What should be in the .htaccess file to make this work?

I currently have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
Allow from 148.204.
Allow from googlebot.com google.com
satisfy any
```

New Code

```
RewriteEngine On
 # -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName domain.co.uk
AuthUserFile /home/****/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/****/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp



RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
Allow from 148.204.
Allow from googlebot.com google.com
satisfy any

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]*)/?(.*)::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]


ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: What do you have the the htaccess file right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The htaccess file should look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]*)/?(.*)::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: do I put this htaccess in the public_html or public_html/subdomain folder?

Comment: @JosephNaylor You want this in your `public_html` directory.

Comment: this still brings my public_html/index.php page up and not public_html/subdomain/index.php - I've put in my htaccess exactly what you have and nothing else

Comment: do I have to put a modrewrite on or something?

Comment: @JosephNaylor yes, you need `RewriteEngine On`, and make sure you have mod_rewrite loaded in your httpd.conf. I assumed you already have done all that stuff because you're using rules already

Comment: can you edit the above answer to the exact htaccess please - its still not working for me

Comment: @JosephNaylor that's exactly what that rule is supposed to look like. You need to add a `RewriteEngine On` at the top of your htaccess file. Then you need to add the above rules below the rules that you already have.

Comment: added code - see new code as above - my fixed subdomain works but my wildcard subdomain goes to a page not found - can you help please

Comment: @JosephNaylor where is the wildcard subdomain's document root point to?

Comment: the wildcard is at public_html/subdomain/ set up with cpanel i.e. * wildcard and in the new subdomain folder public_html/subdomain Basically I have the normal index.php as the main website. I then have fixed subdoains which work set as public_html/middlesex/ for example and then I have the wildcard subdomain which is placed in public_html/subdomain/ index.php etc . The actual subfolder is called subdomain

Comment: @JosephNaylor do you mean that you literally have a directory called `public_html/subdomain/` and that subdomains aren't being mapped to a wildcard directory?

Comment: yes - I set up a wildcard subdomain ( * ) and put it in a folder called subdomain (literally). I placed my index.php script in there which was all working fine until I accidently changed the htaccess file. I have a main public_html/index.php as the main website and other fixed subdomains as well which is why I placed the wildcard subdomain here

Comment: @JosephNaylor if that's the case, then replace `/%1/$1` with `/subdomain/$1`

Comment: Thanks very much - last question - do I need the 4th paragraph code which starts with [RewriteEngine On <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>] as it looks like similar to yours? AND which folder to I put the htaccess in - public_html or publi_html/subdomain?

Comment: @JosephNaylor The one with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`? no, it does the same thing as the next rule that you have

Comment: and the last bit in my last question - AND which folder to I put the htaccess in - public_html or publi_html/subdomain? @JonLin

Comment: @JosephNaylor in the root (public_html)